# Too many futurecalls: 51

Tags: apex, trigger, future

I got the following email:
Sandbox: Developer script exception from

> ContactTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many futurecalls: 51

**Important addition:** I do not see that mentioned 50 calls were executed in my HTTP call's handler logs.

Indeed I do some future calls upon contact inserting/updating in the loop, but I don't see so many contacts created in bulk in our Salesforce instance.
Actually at the time I received this letter no contacts were created at all.

Here is some code:

```
    trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {

    ...

    if(tc.isAfter){
        // call handler instance to meet new registration requirements
        new ContactHelper().execute(tc);
    }
}
```

and the helper

```
public class ContactHelper extends GenericTrigger {

    public override void execute(TriggerContext tc)
    {
        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            return;
        }
        List<Contact> affectedContacts = tc.newList;
        if (tc.isInsert) {
            for (Contact contact: affectedContacts)
            {
                if (!contact.Greylist__c) {
                    updatePartnerPortal(contact.id, 'contact_inserted');
                }
            }
        }

        if(tc.isUpdate) {
            for (Contact contact: affectedContacts)
            {
                if (contact.PersonID__c == null && !contact.Greylist__c) {
                    updatePartnerPortal(contact.id, 'contact_updated');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void updatePartnerPortal(string contactId, string operationType)
    {
        // HTTP call
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue there, right. But due to missing white space in the email I got I could not find it be exact wording before asking.

Comment: Also, please, see my addition: I do not see that mentioned 50 calls were executed in my HTTP call's handler logs.

Comment: @MaksimRamanovich You will not see the results in your remote server's logs. Future methods are enqueued by Salesforce and executed once the transaction commits successfully. Because a limit error is thrown, the transaction doesn't commit and the future calls are rolled back (never executed).

Comment: That makes a great sense. Thank you

Comment: @DavidReed I would keep my question (unmark as duplicate) by two reasons:
1. It is searchable by the info received in exception email from Sforce;
2. Because of your explanation that future calls are enqueued - this was my main confusion, actually.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you bulkify that @future method to accept a `list<string> contactIds` and `string operationtype`. Then, all you'd need do is inside your for loop if(tc.isUpdate) add each one to the list of contactIds. At the end of your trigger execution, you can then call your @future method `if(!contactIds.isEmpty() == true)`. You'll need two lists, one for the isInsert and one for isUpdate. Otherwise you'd need to modify your @future method to accept a map.

Answer (score 0):

This future call runs not only after insert but also after update according to this code.

```
    if(tc.isUpdate) {
        for (Contact contact: affectedContacts)
        {
            if (contact.PersonID__c == null && !contact.Greylist__c) {
                updatePartnerPortal(contact.id, 'contact_updated');
            }
        }
    }
```

Besides that it is really bad practice to not bulk such operations. In the end you'll constantly get such errors.

Comment: Nice catch, but the point is that due to condition it may be executed only once for object. But it makes sense, thanks

Comment: Also, please, see my addition: I do not see that mentioned 50 calls were executed in my HTTP call's handler logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to perform bulk HTTP calls, you could use a chained queueable to perform one HTTP callout per queued job:

Pass the record Ids into the chained queueable implementation:

```
Set<Id> recordIds = new Set<Id>();
new ExampleChainedQueueable(recordIds).enqueueJob();
```

Implementation:

```
public class ExampleChainedQueueable extends AbstractChainedQueueable {

    public ExampleChainedQueueable(Set<Id> recordIds) {
        super(recordIds);
    }

    public override void processRecord(Id recordId) {
        // do HTTP call out here
    }

    public override AbstractChainedQueueable createJob(Set<Id> ids) {
        return new ExampleQueueable(ids);
    }
}
```

Abstract Chained Queueable class:

```
public abstract class AbstractChainedQueueable implements Queueable {

    private Set<Id> recordIds;

    public AbstractChainedQueueable(Set<Id> recordIds) {
        this.recordIds = recordIds;
    }

    public abstract void processRecord(Id recordId);

    public abstract AbstractChainedQueueable createJob(Set<Id> ids);

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

        if (recordIds.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Id recordId = getNextInvoiceId();

        processRecord(recordId);

        processNextInvoice();
    }

    private void processNextInvoice() 
    {
        enqueueJob(this.recordIds);
    }

    private void enqueueJob(Set<Id> ids) {

        if (ids.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // create next job
        AbstractChainedQueueable job = createJob(ids);

        // queue next job
        Id jobId = System.enqueueJob(job);

        System.debug(jobId);
    }

    public void enqueueJob() {

        // queue job
        Id jobId = System.enqueueJob(this);

        System.debug(jobId);
    }

    private Id getNextInvoiceId() {

        // get next record
        Id recordId;
        for(Id item : recordIds) {
            recordId = item;
            break;
        }

        // remove recordId
        recordIds.remove(recordId);

        return recordId;
    }
}
```

Source

- [Github: Salesforce Chained Queueable Abstract Apex Class](https://gist.github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/03e1fb77e317d4ddeb4b393794daf65e)